# How to correctly format a nested bash command in Dockerfile?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

UPDATE: The command is not valid JSON. Docker will use the "exec form" of `RUN` when it detects a valid JSON array, else if invalid JSON is detected then it falls back to using the "shell form" of `RUN`.

```
["bash", "-c", "bash -c 'echo SHLVL: \$SHLVL'"] << \$ is illegal JSON!
```

But if I add an extra `\` then Bash won't do variable expansion on `SHLVL`. Instead it prints `SHLVL: $SHLVL`. See details at https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40140#issuecomment-546638065

---

A nested bash instance increments the `SHLVL` environment variable (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html).

For example:

```sh
$ echo $SHLVL
1
$ bash -c "echo \$SHLVL"
2
$ bash -c "bash -c 'echo \$SHLVL'"
3
```

I'm trying to do this same command in my Dockerfile but I'm getting an error (**see this in my Github Actions** https://github.com/dgroomes/docker-shell-example/commit/20ee36e913729b7cbf7f0e46ffebf359af5cf1a9/checks?check_suite_id=282718710#step:6:20).

```
Step 3/3 : RUN ["bash", "-c", "bash -c 'echo SHLVL: \$SHLVL'"]
 ---> Running in 2255c65b43c9
/bin/sh: 1: [bash,: not found
```

Is it a character escaping problem by the combination of Dockerfile + Bash?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue with the code you've posted on Debian 10, and I'm even getting 14 steps instead of the 15 you're seeing. In particular, for `Step 11/14 : RUN bash -c echo SHLVL: $SHLVL`, I'm getting `SHLVL: 1` instead of your error

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks for trying it out! I've reduced the example in my repo and I've reduced my question. Can you try again?

Comment: I also opened an issue https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40140. I tried so many combinations of escaping and no resolution.

Comment: Also separated out the "SHLVL" part of this question into a different question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58573830/bash-instances-are-not-nesting-in-dockerfile-run

Answer (score 0):

Your container does not have bash installed, use `sh -c` instead to run your command. Nonetheless, most looks like the container already runs `/bin/sh` for your commands. Which means running `echo SHLVL: \$SHLVL` is enough.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, the container does have bash installed. The first `RUN` instruction works correctly which shows that bash is installed https://github.com/dgroomes/docker-shell-example/commit/20ee36e913729b7cbf7f0e46ffebf359af5cf1a9/checks?check_suite_id=282718710#step:6:17

Answer (score 0):

The character escaping is "a problem" in the sense that it is unnecessary in this example.

Try this Dockerfile and see the explanation in the similar question: [Bash instances are not nesting in Dockerfile `RUN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58573830/bash-instances-are-not-nesting-in-dockerfile-run)

```
FROM debian:10
RUN ["bash", "-exc", "bash -exc 'echo SHLVL: $SHLVL'"]
RUN ["bash", "-exc", ":; bash -exc ':; echo SHLVL: $SHLVL'"]
```

So why is escaping unnecessary here:
In the first variant, the outer bash executes the command:

```
bash -exc 'echo SHLVL: $SHLVL'
```

Due to the use of single quotes, no escaping is needed. Follow the expansion of the variables by means of the `x` setting for bash and check the Dockerfile build output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  14.85kB
Step 1/3 : FROM debian:10
 ---> 8e9f8546050d
Step 2/3 : RUN ["bash", "-exc", "bash -exc 'echo SHLVL: $SHLVL'"]
 ---> Running in 07aaddefac26
+ bash -exc 'echo SHLVL: $SHLVL'
SHLVL: 1
+ echo SHLVL: 1
Removing intermediate container 07aaddefac26
 ---> e82b3fc4b569
Step 3/3 : RUN ["bash", "-exc", ":; bash -exc ':; echo SHLVL: $SHLVL'"]
 ---> Running in 1257c43b276d
+ :
+ bash -exc ':; echo SHLVL: $SHLVL'
+ :
+ echo SHLVL: 2
SHLVL: 2
Removing intermediate container 1257c43b276d
 ---> cfa749c16631
Successfully built cfa749c16631
Successfully tagged test:latest
```