# Bash instances are not nesting in Dockerfile `RUN`

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

A nested bash instance increments the SHLVL environment variable (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html).

For example:

```
$ echo $SHLVL
1
$ bash -c "echo \$SHLVL"
2
$ bash -c "bash -c 'echo \$SHLVL'"
3
```

See that at https://github.com/dgroomes/docker-shell-example/commit/60091eb63545f24a9fb3ccf38649ea5098bdbd0d/checks?check_suite_id=283012138#step:5:2

**But when I try the same in a Dockerfile, the SHLVL stays at 1. Why?**

See the Minimal, Reproducible Example at https://github.com/dgroomes/docker-shell-example/blob/60091eb63545f24a9fb3ccf38649ea5098bdbd0d/Dockerfile#L5. And for more proof, the execution of this Dockerfile in the CI tool Github Actions at https://github.com/dgroomes/docker-shell-example/commit/60091eb63545f24a9fb3ccf38649ea5098bdbd0d/checks?check_suite_id=283012138#step:8:15

Here is the problem distilled down to 4 lines (it should print 2 and then 0):

```
Step 2/2 : RUN bash -c "bash -c 'echo \$SHLVL; echo \$BASH_SUBSHELL'"
 ---> Running in ce2362419426
1
0
```

Comment: Try using '$BASH_SUBSHELL' instead and see if that helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @EyalGolan, I tried that <https://github.com/dgroomes/docker-shell-example/commit/c43709fd6580c5d2ab57514c229c014253fcd138/checks?check_suite_id=282782289#step:8:24>

And that part is working as I would expect, where `BASH_SUBSHELL` increments only in subshells, but not nested shells (I don't quite get how Bash keeps track of this difference, but it is explained in examples <http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html#SUBSHELL>)

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the detailed explanation :)

Comment: Interesting. Did you try replacing `"` with `'`? i.e. `RUN ['bash', '-c', 'bash -c "echo SHLVL: \$SHLVL"']`

Comment: @Maroun Good suggestion, I tried the `'` and it errors the same way

Comment: I suspect that bash isn't actually bash inside the environment the dockerfile runs in, suppose 'bash' is just an alias for /bin/sh, then /bin/sh -c "/bin/sh -c 'echo \$SHLVL'" is 1. Could you play around and see if you can find out what path 'bash' actually resolves to.

Comment: @Countingstuff Why when using `sh` it would be 1? Should be 3 as well, no?

Comment: @Maroun, no I don't think so. I notice if you do it in git bash you do get 3, but that's not really indicative of a proper linux terminal (in fact in git bash I suspect that /bin/sh == /bin/bash). As for why it should be 1, simply because I believe this business of increasing SHLVL isn't something inherent to sh.

Comment: "when I try the same" -- please extract and provide a [mcve], even if just to rule out that it's caused by other actions or a misinterpretation on your side.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is possibly still incomplete, but fascinated by the problem, I have taken some time to debug it using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:10
SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-ec"]
RUN apt-get update > /dev/null; apt-get -y install psmisc > /dev/null

# First layer is good: expected 1, got 1
RUN /bin/bash -exc "pstree; echo SHLVL=\$SHLVL"

# The surprising example (getting the escaping right is already tricky)
RUN /bin/bash -exc "/bin/bash -exc \"pstree; echo SHLVL=\\\$SHLVL\"" # expected 2, got 1
RUN /bin/bash -exc "/bin/bash -exc \"/bin/bash -exc \\\"pstree; echo SHLVL=\\\\\\\$SHLVL\\\"\"" # expected 3, got 1

# Now what happens if two commands run in the inner bash
RUN /bin/bash -exc ":; /bin/bash -exc \":; pstree; echo SHLVL=\\\$SHLVL\"" # expected 2, got 1
RUN /bin/bash -exc ":; /bin/bash -exc \":; /bin/bash -exc \\\":; pstree; echo SHLVL=\\\\\\\$SHLVL\\\"\"" # expected 3, got 1
```

The interesting thing seems to be: In case a `bash` invocation is followed directly by another one, it will be "optimized" (?) away. As far as I can tell, this is not a Docker-specific thing, because it can be reproduced interactively (on my Debian 10 system, the interactive command sequence from the question produces 1, 2, 2 and not 1, 2, 3 for the nesting!).

In any case, the output from building the Dockerfile is as follows:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  30.21kB
Step 1/8 : FROM debian:10
 ---> 8e9f8546050d
Step 2/8 : SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-ec"]
 ---> Running in 3509ef249c45
Removing intermediate container 3509ef249c45
 ---> 8956c1fddb7c
Step 3/8 : RUN apt-get update > /dev/null; apt-get -y install psmisc > /dev/null
 ---> Running in 5cabec19144a
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Removing intermediate container 5cabec19144a
 ---> 64cad97f7793
Step 4/8 : RUN /bin/bash -exc "pstree; echo SHLVL=\$SHLVL"
 ---> Running in 22a0aa663163
+ pstree
sh---bash---pstree
+ echo SHLVL=1
SHLVL=1
Removing intermediate container 22a0aa663163
 ---> 4caa146b24f6
Step 5/8 : RUN /bin/bash -exc "/bin/bash -exc \"pstree; echo SHLVL=\\\$SHLVL\"" # expected 2, got 1
 ---> Running in 538ff45db230
+ /bin/bash -exc 'pstree; echo SHLVL=$SHLVL'
+ pstree
sh---bash---pstree
SHLVL=1
+ echo SHLVL=1
Removing intermediate container 538ff45db230
 ---> 1d4c9c2638fa
Step 6/8 : RUN /bin/bash -exc "/bin/bash -exc \"/bin/bash -exc \\\"pstree; echo SHLVL=\\\\\\\$SHLVL\\\"\"" # expected 3, got 1
 ---> Running in 3f0650d4d21b
+ /bin/bash -exc '/bin/bash -exc "pstree; echo SHLVL=\$SHLVL"'
+ /bin/bash -exc 'pstree; echo SHLVL=$SHLVL'
+ pstree
sh---bash---pstree
SHLVL=1
+ echo SHLVL=1
Removing intermediate container 3f0650d4d21b
 ---> 2d977033884d
Step 7/8 : RUN /bin/bash -exc ":; /bin/bash -exc \":; pstree; echo SHLVL=\\\$SHLVL\"" # expected 2, got 1
 ---> Running in 39b79af0f558
+ :
+ /bin/bash -exc ':; pstree; echo SHLVL=$SHLVL'
+ :
+ pstree
sh---bash---bash---pstree
+ echo SHLVL=2
SHLVL=2
Removing intermediate container 39b79af0f558
 ---> 48170e9bcb01
Step 8/8 : RUN /bin/bash -exc ":; /bin/bash -exc \":; /bin/bash -exc \\\":; pstree; echo SHLVL=\\\\\\\$SHLVL\\\"\"" # expected 3, got 1
 ---> Running in 456e6ec421ca
+ :
+ /bin/bash -exc ':; /bin/bash -exc ":; pstree; echo SHLVL=\$SHLVL"'
+ :
+ /bin/bash -exc ':; pstree; echo SHLVL=$SHLVL'
+ :
+ pstree
sh---bash---bash---bash---pstree
+ echo SHLVL=3
SHLVL=3
Removing intermediate container 456e6ec421ca
 ---> 30a07d3bdc95
Successfully built 30a07d3bdc95
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

Finally, the `pstree` output is interesting because it shows how there is actually no other bash process running at the respective points (i.e. the variable tracks the actual shell nesting correctly in all of the cases, it is just that sometimes there are less shells running than expected).

Answer (score 0):

Just had a proper look now, I first observe the following, go in a Dockerfile, and type something like 'RUN gfddlgjkdlfgjk', it will error and tell you

`'/bin/sh -c gfddlgjkdlfgjk' returned a non-zero code`

From this we deduce that

`RUN bash -c "bash -c 'echo \$SHLVL'"`

Actually executes

`/bin/sh -c "bash -c \"bash -c 'echo \$SHLVL'\""`

Which is indeed 1 outside of Docker